# Is it correct to use "complete" instead of "completely" in "And I knew it complete When I wore a younger man's clothes"?

Tags: lyrics, object-complements

> And I knew it complete when I wore a younger man's clothes

Is that sentence correct?
I think that **complete** is an adjective there.
So I think it should be converted to **completely**.
I am not a native English speaker, so my thought may be wrong.

If that is a correct sentence, then, is **complete** an adjective which is an object complement there?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the text, so we can read the passage in context? You could also include the *whole stanza* in your question  It is rare when one statement can be truly analyzed on its own.

Comment: @GoDucks Sorry not to include the passage. I lost the web address of it. If I may, can I ask you whether the sentence you mentioned "It is rare when one statement can be truly analyzed on its own." is correct or not? I think "when" in the sentence should be replaced with "that". I am poor at English and I am a foreigner who is learning English. The reason I ask this is purely to learn English, but not for any else. Thank you.

Comment: *Complete* is being used as a flat adverb. Search this site, or the whole Internet for 'flat adverb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually "complete" used as an adverb. Adjectives were occasionally used as adverbs in older forms of English, and still are in some dialects.

You probably shouldn't try and use this in everyday speech, though, you'll get some strange looks.

As a final point: You really shouldn't be looking for proper grammar in lyrical music.

Edit: On second thought, this might not be right here. I know I've seen this outside of lyrics, using the word "intire" (archaic spelling of entire) instead of complete. But as you might be able to tell from the spelling, that was Early Modern English at the earliest. That's a few hundred years ago.

I'm going to say that it's equally likely that it's just short for "I knew it in complete form" and they took out some unnecessary words to fit the rhyme and meter.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer! This is a tough one, and could be a controversial topic. Your answer was very helpful. But is there no possibility that "complete" is an adjective there?

Comment: Why would it be an adjective? It describes the knowing. It's no less complete now that he doesn't remember it well, in my opinion. But he doesn't know it in complete anymore.

Comment: If I may, can I ask you an additional English question to you? In your statement, you said "Adjectives were occasionally used as adverbs in older forms of English." and I would like to know whether it is also okay to use "form" instead of "forms" in the sentence. And I also would like to know if there is any way that "English" can be the main noun instead of "form" in the phrase "in older form of English". Do you get what I mean? Thank you so much for helping and teaching!